Question for Singularities, Laurent Series of $\csc\big(\frac{1}{z}\big)$.
I came across this question in my complex analysis class. We were given $\csc(1/z)$, and told to classify the singularity at $z=0$, alongside computing the residue at $z=0$.
I did some digging around previous discussions on this site, and discovered numerous discussions surrounding the nature of $\sin\big(\frac{1}{z}\big)$ and $\csc\big(\frac{1}{z}\big)$ at $z=0$ (mainly, this one, explaining how there does not exist a Laurent Series for $\csc(1/z)$ at z=0, and this one, which is similar to my question).
In order to solve this type of problem, I'd look at the Laurent Series of the function to determine singularities, residues, etc. I suppose my main question is, why does there not exist a Laurent expansion for $\csc(1/z)$ at $z=0$? What do answers like this mean when they say "limit of poles"?

It seems that this answer you linked solves your doubts (?)
